# Pros and cons of GitX vs GitNub?

Tags: git, usability, gitx, gitnub

I have very close to zero experience of comandline-operation(copy paste from tutorials pretty much). What are the pros and cons of [gitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) vs [gitNub](http://www.ohloh.net/p/gitnub) from aspects such as Efficiency, learnabillity/learning curve, feature richness and ofcourse esthetics! I have no experience with git.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, you're asking to compare a git GUI with a git hosting service.

Comment: Same here. GitX is GUI for your local repository where you can see what you changed (diff), commit it and see the history. GitHub is a web application where you can see the history as well, but do not perform commits. But here you have you own wiki, issue tracking and code sharing with other developers. My tip: Use both ;)

Comment: Further clarification: GitHub hosts a repository for you, and will give you some web-based interaction (e.g. browse history). GitX lets you interact with your *local* repository, which will be pushing to and fetching from the one on GitHub.

Comment: If you're looking for a git UI Smart Git is the best one I've seen and I believe it works on all 3 major platforms.

Comment: Do you mean GitX vs. GitNub? Looks so, since you used the `gitnub` tag... https://github.com/Caged/gitnub

Comment: @Andrew: That does look nice - although it's odd to me that it costs money and it *still* doesn't support all git features.

Comment: Kristoffer: I suspect there actually is something reasonable you're trying to ask, whether it's gitnub (not github) or something else. Please edit your question to clarify! (Your question is currently one vote from being closed. If it gets closed and you fix it up, I'll immediately vote to reopen!)

Comment: @Kristoffer: I added a couple of links that I hope help.  Feel free to delete them or change them if you know better resources to link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install GitNub and I given up ...
Anyway as they are both Git front end, they should have the same concept (git ones) and so be roughly equivalent in term of learning curves and feature.
Personaly I'm quite happy with GitX and would be probably be too with GitNub if I could install it in less than 2mn.
Anyway , for a better git experience learn the commands ;-)

Comment: Does it provide all nessesary basic functionality?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Some basic command as clone, and push etc , needs to be done "manually". Gitx provides mostly commands that feel better with a GUI , i.e. visual related stuff (as browsing tree, diff etc). For command like git clone , where you need to type anyway a URL there is no need to use a GUI for that (and where I need to type something I prefer to do in a terminal rather than in text field which usuall is to small). I guess that's the same anyway with GitNub.

Answer (score 1):

I use GitX for some tasks and to have an overview of my projects but in my opinion now would be a very good time for you to start using the command line and getting used to it little by little.

There are very few Git commands to learn in order to have a good Git work-flow and it's worth the initial trouble.

I used to be intimidated by by the command line but now feel very comfortable with it. If an idiot such as myself can do it, anybody can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you get some expertise with Git.

Read chapters 1,2 and 3. With that you will have a solid understanding of what the gui are doing. I will take more or less 1 h.

http://book.git-scm.com/

As for the question, I use Gitx on Mac. It is quite good. It allows you to cherry pick lines in a file to commit ( and not commit other lines in the same file).

I am an intermediate Git user. I use Gitx mainly for cherry picking files to commit since it is more easy to select the files from a list than to git add app/controller/... and also I like to write detailed commit messages and it is easier in a GUI than in command line (line breaks and such).

Of course, if you want to add everything, just do a 'git commit -a -m', no need to use GUI.